# PHP add <b> on specified digit

Tags: php, regex

How to add html tag `<b> tag` on specified digit?
I have many data with this format 008008.2.01
but I want to add bold tag on last 2 digit
it should be 008008.2.**01** how do I do it? preg_match? or something?
format is fixed in xxxxxx.x.xx

Thanks

Comment: `substr` ? `$a = 008008.2.01; echo substr ($a, 0, -2) . '<b>' . substr ($a, -2) . '</b>';`

Comment: okay thank you niols solved :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d+)$/', "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('~\b(\d{6}\.\d.)(\d{2})\b~', '\1<b>\2</b>', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wT0cE5/1)

Comment: Thank you this answer is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Do you only need ".01" in bold, but not ".02"? Then I'd do `str_replace(".01",".<b>.01</b>",$string)`, , otherwise Niols' substr-suggestion is the way to go...

Comment: sorry I mean .01 is dynamic, not fixed number str replace .01 should only replace .01 but not for .02

Comment: So you only want to print a certain digit in bold, right? Is it one value only (like ".01") or more?

Comment: Thank you for replying :D
I mean bold only for 2 last digit number

Comment: Ok, in that case Niols' reply should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$digit = '008008.2.01';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\.(\d{2})$/', function($matches){
    return '.<b>'.$matches[1].'</b>';
}, $digit);
```

Result for `008008.2.01` -> `008008.2.<b>01</b>`

Result for `008008.2.05` -> `008008.2.05`

Comment: Thank you for reply! sorry .01 is dynamic, it only replace 01 string :)

Comment: So what you want to bold, only last two chars in all cases?

Comment: Yes that what i mean, I have said before I have many data with this format, not only that fixed number, thank you for replying :D

Comment: Why using `preg_replace_callback` when `preg_replace` can do the job?